# How to show only directory using `v-treeview` in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to show the only directory/folders using `v-treeview`. The response object is coming as a parent-child combination

- If the parent is a folder then the type is `directory`
- If the child is a file then the type is `file`

Below is my code:

```
<v-treeview v-model="tree" :items="fileStructure" activable item-key="path" :open="open" :filter="filter" :search="search" open-on-click>
          <template v-slot:prepend="{ item, open }">
            <v-icon v-if="item.type == 'directory'" color="blue-grey darken-1">
              {{ open ? 'mdi-folder-open' : 'mdi-folder' }}
            </v-icon>
          </template>
          <template v-if="item.type == 'directory'" slot="label" slot-scope="{ item }">
            <a @click="showSelectedSubFolders(item)" v-if="item.type == 'directory'">{{ item.name }}</a>
          </template>
</v-treeview>
```

Now, Using the above code files are not showing under the folder, but when clicking on the folder it is creating a blank space.

The behavior that I want is- It should show only folders. If any folders have subfolders then show an open icon to open subfolders otherwise not required. If any folders/subfolders have only files the no need to show an open icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to show folders I suggest to filter the `fileStructure` with a computed property:

```js
computed: {
  filteredItems() {
    const temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.fileStructure))
    
    function f(item) {
      if(item.children) {
        item.children = item.children.filter(f)
      }
      return item.type === "directory"
    }

    return temp.filter(f)
  }
}
```

This created a deep copy of `fileStructure` so we don't alter the original array. Then the items are recursively filtered for the type directory.
That way we can get rid of the ifs in the html and only need to check if an item has children.

```html
<v-treeview v-model="tree" :items="filteredItems" activable item-key="path" :open="open" :filter="filter" :search="search" open-on-click>
  <template v-slot:prepend="{ item, open }">
    <v-icon v-if="item.children && item.children.length > 0" color="blue-grey darken-1">
      {{ open ? 'mdi-folder-open' : 'mdi-folder' }}
    </v-icon>
  </template>
  <template slot="label" slot-scope="{ item }">
    <a @click="showSelectedSubFolders(item)">{{ item.name }}</a>
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```

Comment: I like this idea. I have to show all the files under the selected folder on the right side. Do you have any idea why can I do that? @Jay Fridge

Comment: Since this answer solved your question I would suggest you accept it and then ask another question regarding your new problem.